# LINQ Convert string to datetime

Tags: linq, string, datetime

In SQL I do it like this:

```
DateMonth=convert(datetime, convert(char(6), AASI.Inv_Acctcur) + '01')
```

How to do it in LINQ? String is in following format:

```
"yyyyMMdd"
```

Thanks,
Ile

EDIT:

Example of SQL usage:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '20161023', 112) -- yyyymmdd
```

Found here: http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

Comment: maybe I'm missing your point but in Linq the column `datatime` is already a `DateTime`, so you can just do `datetime.Month`. And if `datetime` is a string in the database you could use `DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(datetime)`. But this has nothing to do with Linq.

Comment: AASI.Inv_Acctcur is a 6 character string which needs to be converted to datetime, so I add '01' to this string. I tried DateTime.Parse(datetime + "01") but this doesn't work. It's actually this DateTime.Parse("20101001")

Answer (score 4):

[This page on MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882655.aspx) lists all convert methods that `LINQ to SQL` does not support.

`Convert.ToDateTime` is not listed in there. So, I guess you could just use `Convert.ToDateTime` to do what you want.

Comment: But the problem is that my string is in format "yyyyMMdd", so if I try Convert.ToDateTime("20101001") this is not working. And my question is how to do conversion in one line

Answer (score 2):

This is not something typically for LINQ or any LINQ over Expression trees enabled provider (such as LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Entities, LINQ to NHibernate, LLBLGen Pro, etc, etc). This is simply a language question. You want to know how to convert the format yyyyMMdd to a `DateTime`.

The trick is to leave the conversion OUT of your LINQ (over Expression trees) query, because a LINQ provider will not be able to convert it, or if it can, you will get very provider specific implementation.

Therefore, the trick is to get it out of the database as a string (or of course even better: change your database model) and convert it to a `DateTime` in .NET. For instance:

```
// Doing .ToArray is essential, to ensure that the 
// query is executed right away.
string[] inMemoryCollectionStrings = (
    from item in db.Items
    where some_condition
    select item.Inv_Acctcur).ToArray();

// This next query does the translation from string to DateTime.
IEnumerable<DateTime> dates =
    from value in inMemoryCollectionStrings
    select DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyyMMdd", 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In other words, you can use the following line to make the conversion:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I think it is good to mention that in your example you first get all the data into the memory and then filter the result. If there are tons of data it might be better to find another way..

Comment: @OncelUmutTURER: I though that this was implied by the `inMemoryCollectionStrings` variable name :-)